# threats for sleepmode

Tags: sleep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the impact of leaving a laptop in “sleep” mode (while on battery power)?](https://superuser.com/questions/45397/what-is-the-impact-of-leaving-a-laptop-in-sleep-mode-while-on-battery-power)

is there any problem (other than a minor loss of power to battery) if i keep my laptop in sleepmode for a day or 2?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/45397/what-is-the-impact-of-leaving-a-laptop-in-sleep-mode-while-on-battery-power

Answer (score 1):

No, I do that quite often.

Comment: I second that, I do it every day and weekend

Answer (score 0):

I do it all the time, but I wonder how "minor" the "minor loss of power to battery" is. My Macs have [Safe Sleep](http://www.macworld.com/article/53460/2006/10/safesleep.html), and indeed I've relied on that a few times. So: if you're unsure how long your battery will last, then there might be data loss unless things are saved on the hard disk as well.