# Power consumption: laptop in sleep mode

Tags: laptop, power-supply, sleep, power-management

I found out there's a post calculating the [power consumption cost](https://superuser.com/questions/1103136/windows-10-desktop-does-sleep-mode-use-a-lot-of-energy), which tested on a PC. However, I haven't found any data that is related to laptops, or any software to test the power consumption. If the power consumption confined in a range, what would the range be and how many watts are used in sleep mode? Thanks.

p.s. my laptop model is aspire e5-575g

Comment: I'd suggest buying a kill-a-watt style power meter. They're not too expensive and you'll get exact values for your particular laptop.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there would be some study and statistics involved. I'll keep this post and see if anyone has related data.

Comment: My laptop can suspend for 12 hours or more without losing much charge. That means power consumption is trivial. I suggest you look at updating your power drivers.